# Operations on subsets of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Algebraic number theory and Fermat's last theorem, and I just reached the text below (pp 13)

If $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of a ring $R$ we write $X+Y$ for the set of all elements $x+y$ ($x \in X$, $y \in Y$), and $XY$ for the set of all finite sums $\sum x_i y_i$($x_i \in X$, $y_i \in Y$).

I think I understand the $X+Y$. If $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $Y=\{w,z\}$, then $X+Y=\{a+w, a+z, b+w, b+z, c+w, c+z\}$. The $XY$ bit doesn't make much sense to me (particularly because $x$ ad $y$ have the same index $i$). Can someone please tell me what would be the set $XY$ in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example case, the way I read that summation, the product $XY$ would contain
$$
aw,az,bw,bz,cw,cz
$$
as well as any element you can reach by adding together finitely many of these six, in any combination, with repeats allowed. Like, for instance,
$$
0\\
aw+bz\\
aw + az + bw + bz + cw + cz\\
aw+aw+aw+cz
$$